# Spring JMS Session Issue When Using Open MQ

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms, openmq

I'm using spring-jms-3.0.6.RELEASE and open MQ.  Any ideas on why the below exception would be raise?

```
2012-05-02 17:56:18,420 [stuJmsContainer-803059] WARN
org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 

'TestQ' - trying to recover. Cause: 
MQRA:CA:createSession failed-Only one JMS Session allowed when managed connection is involved in a transaction
```

**web.xml:**

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
             <param-value>
                    classpath:/spring/testlistener-context-api.xml
                    classpath:/spring/testmsg-context-api.xml
             </param-value>
        </context-param>
 <listener>
      <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
 </listener> 
 <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

**testlistener-context-api.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="testListener" class="com.test.TestListener" />

    <bean id="executionInterceptor" class="com.test.ExecutionInterceptor" />

     <bean id="testJmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationName" value="TestQ"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="stuMessageListener" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
        <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="100" />
        <property name="receiveTimeout" value="30000" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**testmsg-context-api.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate"/>

    <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.jndi.qconnectionfactory}">

        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTopicConnectionFactory"  class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName" value="${jms.jndi.tconnectionfactory}">

        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="myJMSConnectionFactory" class="com.test.OpenMqConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="imqAddressList" value="${jms.imq.url}" />
        <property name="imqDefaultUsername" value="${jms.imq.user}" />
        <property name="imqDefaultPassword" value="${jms.imq.password}" />
        <property name="imqHost" value="${jms.imq.host}" />
        <property name="imqPort" value="${jms.imq.port}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTopicTemplate"  class="com.test.CustomJMSTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsTopicConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="connectionFactoryName" value="${jms.jndi.tconnectionfactory}"/>
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTemplate"  class="com.test.CustomJMSTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="connectionFactoryName" value="${jms.jndi.qconnectionfactory}"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you supply your JmsContainer configuration ?

Comment: @Nicholas - added my Spring JMS config, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ConnectionAdapter source code](http://mq.java.net/downloads.html) and this archive thread on [OpenMQ mailing list](http://java.net/nonav/projects/mq/lists/users/archive/2008-10/message/39), either Spring or your code itself creates more than one session on a single JMS Connection.

This OpenMQ behavior (raise an error) can be disabled by setting the system property `imq.jmsra.inACC` to `false` but it is not satisfying.

Without transaction manager, Spring uses [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html) to share a single connection for multiple consumers.

You should set [DefaultMessageListenerContainer cacheLevelName](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setCacheLevelName%28java.lang.String%29) property to `CACHE_NONE` so that each consumer thread gets its own session on a single connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response that seemed to fix the issue.  Just to clarify, the cacheLevelName doesn't use the default value of CACHE_NONE because I'm not using a transaction manager?

Comment: Yes exactly: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jms/3.0.7/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java#DefaultMessageListenerContainer.initialize%28%29

Comment: swapping to CACHE_NONE and giving each its own thread now causes another exception:  WARN  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'TestQ' - trying to recover. Cause: MQRA:CFA:allocation failure:createConnection:Error in allocating a connection. Cause: In-use connections equal max-pool-size and expired max-wait-time. Cannot allocate more connections.  Any ideas?

Comment: im using the default for connection pool size 10 (min) 32 (max) and max wait time is 60 seconds.  Tring lowering max wait to 30 seconds

Comment: I guess what wrong: you configure up to 100 max concurrent consumers. With CACHE_NONE, it means up to 100 JMS connections with one session each. So your connection pool is too small. By the way, Spring documentation really recommends to use a transaction manager !

Comment: I upped the pool size to 200 or so and that seemed to fix it.  I agree with you about the transaction manager.  I can see in our code we use to use Springs JmsTransactionManager but its commented out and now the QueueConnectionFactory is configured to use local transaction in the admin console.  I'll read up and hopefully implement the JmsTransactionManager again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I do not think it is relevant to configure up to 200 max concurrent consumer. Depending on what a single consumer is supposed to do, it may have impact on performance: many threads, high CPU usage and probably not enough memory to process 200 messages at the same time. You should do some benchmark and eventually lower that limit...

Comment: Tried rolling out this change into our production servers and I received several exceptions as I outlined here here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627841/connection-failure-using-spring-jms-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-cachelevelna  Any ideas?