# Connection Failure Using Spring-JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer cacheLevelName CACHE_NONE

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

I change my Spring-JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer implementations to use a cacheLevelName of CACHE_NONE and ran into the below exception. The changes were outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419389/spring-jms-session-issue-when-using-open-mq/10523893#comment13640043_10523893).  I'm using glassfish v 2.1, Open MQ 4.4 and Spring 3.*. Any ideas on where I could have gone wrong?

**Web App Log:**

[#|2012-05-16T21:18:12.620+0000|SEVERE|sun-appserver9.1|javax.resourceadapter.mqjmsra.outbound.connection|_ThreadID=284;_ThreadName=updateJmsContainer-90;_RequestID=3aa71c9e-3ac0-4142-b914-ffbdc6e6bb37;|MQJMSRA_MC4001: constructor:Aborting:JMSException on createConnection=[C4000]: Packet acknowledge failed. user=admin, broker=localhost:45088(55601)|#]

2012-05-16 21:18:17,636 [updateJmsContainer-90] WARN  org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'TestQ' - trying to recover. Cause: MQRA:CFA:allocation failure:createConnection:Error in allocating a connection. Cause: MQJMSRA_MC4001: constructor:Aborting:JMSException on createConnection=[C4000]: Packet acknowledge failed. user=admin, broker=localhost:45088(55601)

**Broker Log File:**

```
[16/May/2012:21:10:14 UTC] [B1039]: Broker "appbroker@host:45028" ready.
[16/May/2012:21:10:41 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: guest@206.220.220.111:56811->jms:55601. Count: service=1 broker=1
[16/May/2012:21:10:48 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: guest@206.220.220.111:25432->jms:55601. Count: service=2 broker=2
[16/May/2012:21:10:55 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: guest@206.220.220.111:25478->jms:55601. Count: service=3 broker=3
[16/May/2012:21:11:56 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: guest@206.220.220.73:44040->jms:55601. Count: service=4 broker=4
[16/May/2012:21:11:56 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: guest@206.220.219.227:33237->jms:55601. Count: service=5 broker=5
...
...
[16/May/2012:21:17:50 UTC] [B1065]: Accepting: admin@127.0.0.1:46564->jms:55601. Count: service=500 broker=500

[16/May/2012:21:17:50 UTC] WARNING [B3004]: **No threads are available to process a new connection on service jms. 1000 threads out of a maximum of 1000 threads are already in use by other connections.** A minimum of 2 threads must be available to process the connection. Please either limit the # of connections or increase the imq.<service>.max_threads property. Closing the new connection.
[16/May/2012:21:18:01 UTC] [B1066]:   Closing: ???@127.0.0.1:0->jms:0 because "[B3004]: No threads are available to process a new connection on service jms. 1000 threads out of a maximum of 1000 threads are already in use by other connections. A minimum of 2 threads must be available to process the connection. Please either limit the # of connections or increase the imq.<service>.max_threads property. Closing the new connection. ". Count: service=0 broker=500
[16/May/2012:21:18:01 UTC] WARNING Problem detected while attempting to send notification mq.connection.close from MBean Service Monitor
[16/May/2012:21:18:01 UTC] WARNING Cannot determine service name from connection ID: 7881641671884329217
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This C4000 error is a network generic exception handler. It may be a consequence of the cache level change. The application may open too many connections to the server, depending on your pool setup, and the server may lack resources to manage them - the best guess is probably memory.

Please check your OpenMQ server log files and memory usage.

Is there any network configuration (firewall, QoS router...) between consumer and MQ server that may control connection establishment ? Opening many connections very quickly may be considered as a SYN flood which is a common DoS attack.

Comment: I added my brokers log file above and it seems as though it hit a max number of threads (1000). Is increasing the imq.<servic>.max_threads property the real solution here or is something else wrong?  The memory settings on the broker startup script are  "-Xmx3048m -Xincgc"& Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The real question is: do you really need so many connections/consumers ready at the same time ?

Comment: I can lower the max pool size and try.  For some reason the setup on my test server only goes to 124, i.e. [B1065]: Accepting: admin@206.220.219.238:47378->jms:35425. Count: service=124 broker=124 and doesn't have the max thread issue, while production went to 500, i.e. Count: service=500 broker=500.  The pool settings are the exact same for both, so I'm a bit miffed...the messages being sent to the queues were very close in terms of load.

Comment: I think the issue is that we have a pool connection idle timeout of 300 seconds so connections couldn't be closed before the 1000 thread max was reached.

Comment: Have you really enough ressources so that 500 consumers can process 500 messages at the same time (CPU and memory) ? You should benchmark with less consumers (20 if you have 16 cores for instance) to find the best parallelization options to get the optimal throughput...

Comment: no I don't think the server can handle the load described.  Each of our 5 implementations of the Spring DefaultMessageLisenerContainer use concurentConsumers=5 and maxConcurrentConsumers=100, you're suggesting lowering the maxConcurrentConsumers to 20, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is probably far enough.